# Clip GeoTIFF into small patches using rasterio and patchify Python

Tags: clip, tiles, rasterio

I need to clip a large GeoTIFF into small equal patches to train a Convolutional Neural Network. My patches should have 512x512 pixels and overlap 128. To do this I'm using `rasterio` and `patchify`.

There are some posts about cropping a GeoTIFF but they are not exactly what I'm looking for as they don't need overlapping or be defined-size patches.

My code is able to clip the GeoTIFF according to my needs. However, when converting the raster object to an array I lose the metadata, coordinates and CRS of the patches.

Any ideas on how to do it without losing this information?

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio as rio
#import tifffile as tiff
from patchify import patchify
#from rasterio.plot import show

IMG_PATH = 'D:/data/P_68_X0_4097_X1_5120_Y0_11265_Y1_12288.tif'
OUT_PATH = 'D:/data/patches/'

PATCH_SIZE = 512
PATCH_STEP = 128

# Open raster data and convert to array
img = rio.open(IMG_PATH)
#show(img) # plot raster
img_array = img.read()
print(img_array.shape)

img_array = np.moveaxis(img_array, 0, 2) # move bands to the last dimension of the array
print(img_array.shape)

# Open raster data using tifffile library
#img_array = tiff.imread(IMG_PATH)

# Create patches of [512 pixels in X, 512 pixels in Y, 4 bands] and 128 pixels overlapping
patches = patchify(img_array,
                   (PATCH_SIZE, PATCH_SIZE, 4), step=PATCH_STEP)
print(patches.shape)

for x in range(patches.shape[0]):
    for y in range(patches.shape[1]):
        for z in range(patches.shape[2]):
            single_patch = patches[x,y,z,:,:,:]
            tiff.imwrite(OUT_PATH + 'Image_' + str(x) + '_' + str(y) + ".tiff", single_patch)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need spatial information in each training patch you will need to perform a spatial clip for each patch using `shapely`, for example.
But, keep in mind this process is costly and you cannot use `patchify`.

Normally, when I train a CNN for geospatial data I discard this information. During inferring time, I create the patches without overlapping (patchify) and then recreate (unpatchify) the entire image (for which we have the geospatial metadata) and save it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I appreciate your response. In my case, I need to keep the spatial information for the inference process for a post-refinement of the classification using vector data. I had not thought about using shapeli, it may be a good option. If you have any code examples they are welcome.

Comment: @sermomon You could rasterize the vector data which you want to use for post-refinement beforehand. Thus no need to keep spatial information if you have everything in array / raster / matrix format.